# dynamically created dropdown and onChange jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

My application is in ASP.net MVC3.

I have a table of elements. An element can have child elements, but a child element cannot. In the table, if the element has children, they are listed in a ul. A user can select the items in the list to remove it from that parent. When this happens, the element is removed from the list, and a partial view is rendered that makes a new row in the table for that element since it is no longer a child. Elements that are not children and don't have children of their own are able to be combined with other elements by selecting the element you want to combine it with from a dropdown. My problem is that when you remove an element from a parent, the dropdown created for the table row in the partial view does not have the functionality needed.

I think that this may be due to the fact that my javascript function to combine elements is in the `$(document).ready(function () {...});` and that dropdown is no there on page creation.

is there a way to add my `$('.combineDropdown').change(function () {...});` to an element that has been created dynamically?

Comment: Some code/markup would aid with getting a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use jQuery at all for this? You can acheive the same result by outputting the dropdown with the `onChange` html attribute pointing to a javascript function to be executed.

Example:

```
<select onChange="myFunction(this)"><option>...</option></select>
```

Comment: You can't specify html attributes in MVC3?

Comment: You can, but it's wacky to do inline JavaScript in a modern framework like that. JavaScript should be kept out of the markup!

Comment: You're calling a javascript function on an HTML event. How is this wacky?

Comment: The wackiness is that inline JavaScript is the opposite of best practice. You can set up the event listener and whatever else in an external file (which is what he was trying to do with jQuery) rather than mixing your behavior logic into the markup. There's a delicious irony to using inline JS on a modern framework like MVC3 which includes an "Unobtrusive JavaScript" library!

Comment: So, let me get this straight. Wacky = Opposite of best practice. Jquery selector + binds > simple HTML attribute. All of that in the name of 'pureness'? Please, come back into the real world.

Comment: You are entitled to your opinion, but the industry (and the SO community, from my experience) disagree with you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/), [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) (depending on what you need). This needs to be done each time you add a new element